# Strange behavior of pagination with php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

So I have this `portfolio` page where are loaded items(images) from MySQL database. The HTML is bootstrap and when user click on some category is rearrange all elements and show only from that category.

```
<div class="filters">
            <ul class="wow lightSpeedIn">
                <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat_1">Cat_1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Cat_2">Cat_2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Cat_3">Cat_3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Cat_4">Cat_4</a></li>
            </ul>
</div> <!-- *** end filters *** -->
```

I've made them pulled from database and they work so far but now I want to limit them on the page and put pagination but something strange(at least for me) happening. This is the whole part of the page with items and the pagination.

```
<!-- *****  Portfolio Filters ***** -->
        <div class="filters">
<div class="filters">
            <ul class="wow lightSpeedIn">
                <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat_1">Cat_1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Cat_2">Cat_2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Cat_3">Cat_3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Cat_4">Cat_4</a></li>
            </ul>
</div> <!-- *** end filters *** -->
        </div> <!-- *** end filters *** -->
    </div> <!-- *** end container *** -->

    <!-- *****  Portfolio  wrapper ***** -->
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper margin-bottom-medium">
<?php
    require_once 'misc/database.inc.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 3;
    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY project_id ASC LIMIT $start_from, 8");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
        {
            echo '<div class="portfolio-item '.$row['project_category'].'">';
            echo '<div class="portfolio">';
            echo '<a href="single-project.php?project_id='.$row['project_id'].'" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio">';
            echo '<img src="'.$row['project_image'].'" alt="Portfolio 1">';
            echo '<div class="portfolio-overlay hvr-rectangle-out">';
            echo '<h2 class="margin-bottom-small">

                        <strong class="white-color bold-text"></strong>
                    </h2>';
            echo '<div class="button">See the project</div>';
            echo '</div><!-- END PORTFOLIO OVERLAY -->
              </a>
           </div>
        </div> <!-- *** end  portfolio-item *** -->
        ';
        }
    Database::disconnect();       
?> 


    </div> <!-- *** end  portfolio-wrapper *** -->
 <?php
        echo '<div id="pagination">';

        $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(project_id) FROM projects");
        $result->execute();
        $row = $result->fetch();
        $total_records = $row[0];
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 3);
        //$total_pages=(ceil($total_records/$limit)) + 1;

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='portfolio.php?page=".$i."'";
            if($page==$i)
            {
                echo "id=active";
            }
                echo ">";
                echo "".$i."</a> ";
        };
        echo '</div>';
?>
```

The problem is:

1. When I put `LIMIT` clause in the query it shows 8 items per page but the buttons for categories doesn't work properly. The work only on 1st page and showing only items from categories with id`s between 1 and 8 because of the LIMIT. That means that if I have 8 items loaded on first page and click on category 3 and there are only items with ID's > 8 wont show anything. Also all of this buttons are not working on other pages i.e.`?page=2`..`?page=3` etc.
2. Currently I'm testing with 11 items in database and 8 per page. This mean that I must have only 2 pages under them but there are 4 pages.

*On page 1 is showing 8 items with ID'd from 1-8*.

*On second page is showing items from 4-11???*

*On third page is showing items with ID's from 7 to 11...*

*and on 4th page is showing items with ID's 10 and 11.*

Comment: Take a look into **LIMIT** and **OFFSET** and combine them like [this](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)

Comment: `$start_from = ($page-1) * 3;` surely that should say `* 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says `$start_from = ($page-1) * 3;` but you say that you want to show 8 per page. So you need to multiple by 8 instead of 3:

`$start_from = ($page-1) * 8;`

Again, here:

`$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 3);`

That should probably be `/ 8`

I would recommend setting up a `$perPage` variable and using that throughout your code so that you only need to change it once, to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: Yes, thank's for this. That's fix problem number 1. Any idea about problem `2`?

Comment: Does the second part of my answer not fix it? Changing the formula for `$total_pages`?

Comment: I mean my 1st question. On first page are loaded 8 items `id from 1-8`. So for example if in category 3 all items are with bigger id than 8 I wont see them on first page and same in any other page. If I go on second page I wont see items in category with id's < 8.

Comment: [This is the template that I use](http://choyan.me/demo/KreFolio/index.html#portfolio). Please check where is `

    Print Media
    Icon Design
    Photography
    Web Design
    UI` on the portfolio and how they change. This doesn't work propperly now.

Comment: Hmm... your "load more" button doesn't appear to do anything except scroll to the top of the page. Is that the issue?

Comment: I've change "load more" button with this pagination buttons `[1][2][3]`. The issue is in `Print Media / Icon Design / Photography / Web Design UI`. When I go to `page=2` they didn't show elements with `id < 8` because on page 2 are elements with `id > 8` and so on..On page 3 for example wont show items under id=16. I hope is a bit clear now?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. Are you saying that on page 3 you want to show 1-24?

Comment: Exact opposite. If I'm on 2nd or 3rd or 4th or doesn't matter which page you will see only 8 items. It suppose to be like this because of the query. But if you click on `Photography` and you are on page 2 where you see id's from 9-16 but all your `Photography` projects are with id's which are not in this range you wont see anything under this category.  If you check carefully the link with the template you will see that you can rearrange projects by category. It is logically correct I think but is it possible when you click on category without matter on which page are you to load them?

Comment: OK. Well the logic seems correct to me. It's possible your $_GET variable is getting lost. Do a `var_dump($_GET)` on the page somewhere and see what it says. Might be a rewrite rule conflicting with it

Comment: On `page=1` is this `array(1) {  ["page"]=>  string(1) "1"}` .. on page=2 is `array(1) {  ["page"]=>  string(1) "2"}` and so on. I don't have rewrite rules yet

Comment: Hmm sorry then, I'm not sure what's going on. Would try dumping the data from SQL and see if it's getting the right rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will figured out the other problem. It is not that critical at all.